# Can I make wine from the fields I harvest with the Laborer?

Tags: viticulture

The text for Laborer states:

> Harvest up to 2 fields OR make up to 3 wine. You may lose 1 VP to do both.

If I pay my VP, can I make wine using grapes I have just harvested?

Comment: [Viticulture link at BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/128621/viticulture)

Comment: Yes, that's how we play it, though not sure of the official ruling. And yay, so glad to see Viticulture questions popping up!

Answer (score 2):

Yes I believe you can.

The rules for visitor cards state

> Many visitors have two separate clauses delineated by the all-caps
>   word "OR".  These are two completely independent clauses.

, so in a normal situation you can do just one. However the Labourer is giving you the option to do both so there is no reason why you couldn't do both and thematically losing a point for the labourer to work extra hard makes sense.

When you harvest you add grapes to crush pad.  When making wine you move from crush pad.  There is no rule that says they have to be there a set time limit before they can be made into wine.  There is nothing on the labourer card that says if you choose to do both they happen simultaneously.  You would choose the order they happen in to your advantage.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. A powerful card if true. Is there any official FAQ that makes this explicit?